# How to find at particular mouse position what is the x-axis value and y-axis value?

Tags: .net, winforms, charts

How to find at particular mouse position on chart area (plotted area), what is the x-axis value and y-axis value?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to supply a bit more info about this before getting any good answers. Is the chart being displayed within a charting control of some kind? If so, can't you just hook into the mouse movement event (probably something like OnMouseMove() ) to get the current coordinates? You can also hook into the mouse click event for the asme info.

Answer (score 0):

without any informations about **which chart control** you are using you won't get any help.

Most chart controls out there have some helper methods to get these informations. So take a look at the documentation or tell us what chart you are using.